# Arrays: Personal numbers (CPR)

Tags: java, arrays

I am studying programming atm. We have this assignment: "Create an array that includes Personal numbers (called CPR in Denmark) and print it out".
I have been able to create this but in a very "ugly" way imo. Is there another way of doing this? I am using netbeans.

For those who do not know how a personal number looks it, it looks like this "xxxxxx-xxxx".
My codes looks like this:

```
package arraycpr;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Mo
 */
public class ArrayCPR {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] anArray;
        anArray = new int [6];

        String CPR = "-2931";
        String CPR1 = "-4682";
        String CPR2 = "-4960";
        String CPR3 = "-3729";
        String CPR4 = "-0121";
        String CPR5 = "-1544";
        anArray[0] = 260894-2931; 
        anArray[1] = 200771-4672;
        anArray[2] = 290736-4960;
        anArray[3] = 251087-3729;
        anArray[4] = 290980-0121;
        anArray[5] = 250888-1544;

        System.out.println("CPR: "
                           + anArray[0] + CPR);
        System.out.println("CPR: "
                           + anArray[1] + CPR1);
        System.out.println("CPR: "
                           + anArray[2] + CPR2);
        System.out.println("CPR: "
                           + anArray[3] + CPR3);
        System.out.println("CPR: "
                           + anArray[4] + CPR4);
        System.out.println("CPR: "
                           + anArray[5]+ CPR5);


    }

}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things that are not correct:

- You don't need a scanner as you are not taking any input from user
- You don't need the string that you have
- The array need to be of type `String` since you have a `-` in it.

You code should be like :

```
package arraycpr;

/**
 *
 * @author Mo
 */
public class ArrayCPR {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] anArray;
        anArray = new String[6];
        anArray[0] = "260894-2931"; 
        anArray[1] = "200771-4672";
        anArray[2] = "290736-4960";
        anArray[3] = "251087-3729";
        anArray[4] = "290980-0121";
        anArray[5] = "250888-1544";

        for (String eachString : anArray) {
            System.out.println("CPR: " + eachString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Makes a lot of sense!